# Node app keeps crashing due to exhausted memory after migrated to Windows environment

Tags: node.js, iis, memory-leaks

I am working on a React site that was originally built by someone else. The app uses the Wordpress rest api for handling content.

Currently the live app sits on a nginx server running node v6 and it has been working just fine. However now I have to move the app over to an IIS environment(not by choice) and have been having nothing but problems with it. I have got the app to finally run as expected which is great, but now I am running into an issue regarding the memory in node becoming exhausted.

So when I was debugging this issue I noticed the server's firewall was polling the home route every 5 - 10 seconds, which was firing an api request to the Wordpress api each time. The api then would return a pretty large JSON object of data.

So my conclusion to this was the firewall is polling the home route too often which was killing the memory because then the app had to constantly fire api request and load in huge sets of data over and over.

So my solution was to set up a polling route on the node server(express) which would just return a 200 response and nothing else. This seemed to fix the issue as the app went from crashing every hours to lasting over two days. However after about two days the app crashed again with another memory error. The error looked like this:
[image: memory error]

So since the app lasted much longer with the polling route added in I assume that firewall polling was/is in fact my issue here, however now that I added in the polling route and the app still crashed after a couple days I have no idea what to do which is why I am asking for help.

I am very unfamiliar with working on Windows so I don't know if there are any memory restrictions or any obvious things I could do to help prevent this issue.

Some other notes are: I have tried increasing the `--max-old-space-size` to about 8000 but it didn't seem to do anything so I don't know if I am maybe implementing it wrong but when I start the script I have tried the following commands when starting the app:

`Start-process npm -Argumentlist “run server-prod --max-old-space-size=8192” -WorkingDirectory C:\node\prod`

And when I used forever to handle the process

`forever start -o out.log -e error.log .\lib\server\server.js -c "node --max_old_space_size=8000”`

Any help on what could be the issue or tips on what I should look for woulf be great, again I am very new to working on Windows so maybe there is just something I am missing.